# Is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy\neq 0\}$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

I want to generalize the question: [Is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x,y>0\}$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4483556/1069864)

Let $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy\neq 0\}$. Is $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My attempt: Let divide the $U$ into four parts as follows: $U_ 1 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0,y >0\}$, $U_ 2 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x<0,y >0\}$, $U_ 3 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x<0,y <0\}$ and $U_ 4 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x>0,y <0\}$.

$\fbox{$U_1$ is open:} $ Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Choose $r=\frac{1}{2}(\text{min}\{x,y\})$. Since $x,y>0$, $r>0$. Hence $B_d((x,y), r) \subset U$.  So, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\fbox{$U_2$ is open:} $ Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Choose $r=\frac{1}{2}(\text{min}\{-x,y\})$. Since $-x,y>0$, $r>0$. Hence $B_d((x,y), r) \subset U$.  So, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\fbox{$U_3$ is open:} $ Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Choose $r=\frac{1}{2}(\text{min}\{-x,-y\})$. Since $-x,-y>0$, $r>0$. Hence $B_d((x,y), r) \subset U$.  So, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

$\fbox{$U_4$ is open:} $ Let $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Choose $r=\frac{1}{2}(\text{min}\{x,-y\})$. Since $x,-y>0$, $r>0$. Hence $B_d((x,y), r) \subset U$.  So, $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So, $U = U_1 \cup U_2\cup U_3\cup U_4$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This is your fifth variation of “is this set open?” – how many are there to come?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus U=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x= 0\vee y= 0\right\}$ and this set is obviously closed.

Comment: Why negative vote? I am learning metric space. So, I can be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If we denote
$$
S=(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)\setminus U=\{(x,y):xy=0\},
$$
then $S$ is a closed set since for every point in $S$, say $(a,0)$, there is a sequence of points $(a+\frac1 n,0)\in S$, such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(a+\frac1 n,0)=(a,0)
$$
The same for points of the form $(0,a)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you can make it simpler if you realize that there is no real reason to split $U$, as the argument is always the same. If you considerer a generic point $(x,y) \in U$, its distance to the lines represented by $xy=0$ is given by $\epsilon = \min\{|x|,|y|\}$. Hence, $B_{\epsilon/2}((x,y)) \subset U$, which shows that $U$ is open.